# What is this code running infinitely in C?

Tags: c, extract, infinite-loop

In this program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int a[5],c=0;

int main()
{
    printf("Enter no\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    for(int i=0;a[i];i=+2) {
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to input `12345` and get the output `1 3 5`, but the program never terminates. How can i do this?

Comment: Because `a[i]` is never 0.

Comment: first take five input in array `a` uinsg for loop then put `i+=2` instead of `i+2`

Comment: The value of `i` never changes.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, your code is just all over the place, it looks as if you're just wildly guessing:

1. You can't pass an `int` array to `scanf()`, ask it to read one `int`, and expect it to put all the digits of a multi-digit number into the individual elements all by itself like that. You either need to read in a string, or read in a single `int` and extract the digits yourself.
2. The variable `c` is unused.
3. Your `for` loop makes no sense at all. Even if you had filled all the elements of your array `a`, it still wouldn't make sense, and you haven't.

Here's a sensible version of your code, reading into a string:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char a[6];

    printf("Enter no\n");
    fgets(a, 6, stdin);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += 2) {
        printf("%c ", a[i]);
    }

    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

with output:

```
paul@local:~/Documents/src/sandbox$ ./num
Enter no
12345
1 3 5 
paul@local:~/Documents/src/sandbox$
```

Note that this does nothing to check whether the user actually did enter five characters, which *your* program should do.

Answer (score 2):

the for loop is defined in this way

```
for(initialization ; condition check ; variable update)
```

in your code

```
for(int i=0;a[i];i+2)
{
    printf("%d ",a[i]);
}
```

the condition  part of the for loop is set to a[i], which is probably never false. so the loop runs infinitely. the variable update is also incorrect. i value should be updated.

try

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i+=2)
{
    printf("%d ",a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is running infinitely because nothing changes inside the loop that would cause the loop to terminate. No variable's value is changed anywhere inside the loop. If `a[i]` is true for the first iteration, it will remain true forever since `i`'s value never changes.